# C++ using switch-case return value as a condition for if statement

Tags: c++

May one write something like this in c++:

```
// ...
if(value <= switch(secValue){
   case First:
      return 1;
   case Second:
      return 2;
   return -1;
}){
   //... do some logic ...
} // end if
```

Thanks

Comment: _"May one write something like this in c++:"_ No.

Comment: @Niles Maybe read about the C++20 spaceship operator.

Comment: Stop being fixated on using a 'switch' where it's not suitable and concentrate on writing the most readable code. The 'boring' alternative to this is pretty simple and easy to follow, while the ones forcing use of 'switch' are not.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas You don't know me, haven't seen my code, neither your comment relevant in any way to my question... Should I explain my decisions in public, or it is just you asking me weird questions? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly this, no. But you could get close with a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    // dummy types and values needed for demo
    enum test_enum 
    {
        First, Second
    } secValue = First;
    int value = 1;
    
    if (value <= [secValue]() 
    //            ^ Capture secValue in lambda expression
            {
                switch (secValue) 
                {
                    case First:
                        return 1;
                    case Second:
                        return 2;
                    default: // needed default case. Can't just have a stray return 
                             // in a switch
                        return -1;
                }
            }()) 
    //       ^ immediately invoke lambda    
    {
        std::cout << "Huzah!";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was hoping to get.

Comment: @Niles: Why would you want to bring this upon those who inherit your code?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Does it seem fine asking twice the same question, in two separate places, while it quite obvious you're not expecting an answer?

Comment: @Niles: I'm not asking a question - these are comments and the core point I'm trying to get across is that it's better to write simple code than clever code.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Well, though technically you DID ask a question, I'd thank you for your clever opinion, I guess? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I'm sort-of with Dave on this one. I'd spin this off to a free function in an anonymous namespace in the name of readability. As soon as a lambda gets larger than 3-4 lines I start looking at it as clutter. If the switch starts getting long, consider replacing the whole thing with a `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 3):

Not with a `switch’, but with the ternary operator:

```
if (value <= (secValue == First ? 1
    : secValue == Second ? 2
    : -1)) {
    // . . .
}
```

But you really should put the right-hand side in a function so that the code is more readable.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer using switch here since it makes more sense (there're more than 2-3 values).